# Hyperledger Fabric CA: fatal error: unexpected signal during runtime execution

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

we are using Hyperledger Fabric CA together with an LDAP server. we made an enroll request to the server and got this error as an **unhandled exception** (causes fabric-ca-server to terminate):

```
fatal error: unexpected signal during runtime execution
[signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0x63 pc=0x7f927a0de259]
```

complete trace is very lengthy and can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/siddjain/843e12ef7b841e6342d4a2930eb4d7fd)

How can we fix this? Our command which caused the error is:

```
root@6c497fa7d3f9:/home# fabric-ca-client enroll -d -u https://siddjain:xxx@uber-rca-server:7054 -M siddjain --csr.names C=US --csr.names ST=CA --csr.names L=San Francisco --csr.names O="Uber Inc." --csr.names OU="Digital & Analytics" --tls.certfiles uber-ca-chain.pem --tls.client.certfile uber-client.pem --tls.client.keyfile uber-client.key
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution to this problem is to add an environment variable named GODEBUG and set its value to [netdns=go](https://jira.hyperledger.org/browse/FAB-13419?attachmentOrder=asc) while creating the fabric-ca-server. Example:

```
docker container create --name uber-rca-server --network example_net --env FABRIC_CA_SERVER_HOME=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server --env FABRIC_CA_SERVER_DEBUG=true --env GODEBUG=netdns=go --workdir /etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server --log-opt max-file=3 --log-opt max-size=10m hyperledger/fabric-ca:1.3.0 fabric-ca-server start --ca.certfile uber-rca.pem --ca.keyfile uber-rca.key --ca.name uber-rca --tls.certfile uber-rca-server.pem --tls.keyfile uber-rca-server.key --tls.enabled --tls.clientauth.type requireandverifyclientcert --tls.clientauth.certfiles uber-ca-chain.pem --ldap.enabled --ldap.url ldaps://cn=admin,dc=uber,dc=com:xxx@uber-ldap-server:636/dc=uber,dc=com --ldap.tls.certfiles uber-ca-chain.pem --ldap.tls.client.certfile uber-rca-client.pem --ldap.tls.client.keyfile uber-rca-client.key
```

Comment: Hi Morpheus, this works like a charm. So, Could you please explain what happens behind the screen and how this environment variable resolves the problem?

Comment: On Unix systems, the resolver has two options for resolving names. It can use a pure Go resolver that sends DNS requests directly to the servers listed in /etc/resolv.conf, or it can use a cgo-based resolver that calls C library routines such as getaddrinfo and getnameinfo. see details at https://www.codementor.io/alibabacloud/hyperledger-fabric-deployment-on-alibaba-cloud-environment-sigsegv-problem-analysis-and-solutions-naxdqprd6