# Fabric-CA with SoftHSM: Could not initialize BCCSP PKCS11: Invalid config. It must not be nil

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, pkcs#11, hyperledger-fabric-ca, softhsm

I have followed [softHSM2 repo](https://github.com/opendnssec/SoftHSMv2) to install and initialize the token but when I start the fabric-ca-server container with PKCS11 env variables I get **Could not initialize BCCSP PKCS11: Invalid config. It must not be nil.** according to fabric-ca docs just 4 (default, library, pin, label) env variables are required to use SoftHSM but I tried to add all the fields mentioned under pkcs11 but the issue persists, not sure what part of config is nil.

***docker-compose-ca.yaml***

```
version: '2'

networks: 
  org1_network:
      external: 
        name: org1_network

services: 
  
  ca_org1:
    image: hyperledger/fabric-ca:latest
    environment: 
      - GODEBUG=netdns=go
      - FABRIC_CA_HOME=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_NAME=ca.org1.example.com
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_TLS_ENABLED=true
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_PORT=7054
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_DEBUG=true
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_BCCSP_DEFAULT=PKCS11
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_BCCSP_PKCS11_HASH=SHA2
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_BCCSP_PKCS11_SECURITY=256
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_BCCSP_PKCS11_LIBRARY=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/libsofthsm2.so
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_BCCSP_PKCS11_PIN=98765432
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_BCCSP_PKCS11_FILEKEYSTORE_KEYSTORE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server/msp
      - SOFTHSM2_CONF=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/config.file
    ports: 
      - "7054:7054"
    command: sh -c 'fabric-ca-server start -b org1:adminpw -d'
    volumes: 
      - ../organizations/fabric-ca/org1:/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server
      - ../../softhsm/config.file:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/config.file
      - /../../../usr/local/lib/softhsm/libsofthsm2.so:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/libsofthsm2.so
    container_name: ca_org1
    networks: 
      - org1_network
```

***config.file***

```
# SoftHSM v2 configuration file

directories.tokendir = /tmp/
objectstore.backend = file
objectstore.umask = 0077

# ERROR, WARNING, INFO, DEBUG
log.level = DEBUG

# If CKF_REMOVABLE_DEVICE flag should be set
slots.removable = false

# Enable and disable PKCS#11 mechanisms using slots.mechanisms.
slots.mechanisms = ALL

# If the library should reset the state on fork
library.reset_on_fork = false
```

***fabric-ca-org1-container logs***

```
2021/07/11 21:22:08 [DEBUG] Home directory: /etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server
2021/07/11 21:22:08 [INFO] Configuration file location: /etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server/fabric-ca-server-config.yaml
2021/07/11 21:22:08 [INFO] Starting server in home directory: /etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server
2021/07/11 21:22:08 [DEBUG] Set log level: 
2021/07/11 21:22:08 [INFO] Server Version: 1.5.1-snapshot-38527387
2021/07/11 21:22:08 [INFO] Server Levels: &{Identity:2 Affiliation:1 Certificate:1 Credential:1 RAInfo:1 Nonce:1}
2021/07/11 21:22:08 [DEBUG] Making server filenames absolute
2021/07/11 21:22:08 [DEBUG] Initializing default CA in directory /etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server
2021/07/11 21:22:08 [DEBUG] Init CA with home /etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server and config {Version:1.5.1-snapshot-38527387 Cfg:{Identities:{PasswordAttempts:10 AllowRemove:false} Affiliations:{AllowRemove:false}} CA:{Name:ca.org1.example.com Keyfile: Certfile:ca-cert.pem Chainfile:ca-chain.pem} Signing:0xc00033e210 CSR:{CN:fabric-ca-server Names:[{C:US ST:North Carolina L: O:Hyperledger OU:Fabric SerialNumber:}] Hosts:[dc6f304f9d43 localhost] KeyRequest:0xc0000bf520 CA:0xc0001d5bf0 SerialNumber:} Registry:{MaxEnrollments:-1 Identities:[{ Name:**** Pass:**** Type:client Affiliation: MaxEnrollments:0 Attrs:map[hf.AffiliationMgr:1 hf.GenCRL:1 hf.IntermediateCA:1 hf.Registrar.Attributes:* hf.Registrar.DelegateRoles:* hf.Registrar.Roles:* hf.Revoker:1]  }]} Affiliations:map[org1:[department1 department2] org2:[department1]] LDAP:{ Enabled:false URL:ldap://****:****@<host>:<port>/<base> UserFilter:(uid=%s) GroupFilter:(memberUid=%s) Attribute:{[uid member] [{ }] map[groups:[{ }]]} TLS:{false [] { }}  } DB:{ Type:sqlite3 Datasource:fabric-ca-server.db TLS:{false [] { }}  } CSP:0xc0001d5e00 Client:<nil> Intermediate:{ParentServer:{ URL: CAName:  } TLS:{Enabled:false CertFiles:[] Client:{KeyFile: CertFile:}} Enrollment:{ Name: Secret:**** CAName: AttrReqs:[] Profile: Label: CSR:<nil> Type:x509  }} CRL:{Expiry:24h0m0s} Idemix:{IssuerPublicKeyfile: IssuerSecretKeyfile: RevocationPublicKeyfile: RevocationPrivateKeyfile: RHPoolSize:1000 NonceExpiration:15s NonceSweepInterval:15m}}
2021/07/11 21:22:08 [DEBUG] CA Home Directory: /etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server
2021/07/11 21:22:08 [DEBUG] Checking configuration file version '1.5.1-snapshot-38527387' against server version: '1.5.1-snapshot-38527387'
2021/07/11 21:22:08 [DEBUG] Initializing BCCSP: &{ProviderName:PKCS11 SwOpts:0xc0001d5e60 PluginOpts:<nil> Pkcs11Opts:<nil>}
2021/07/11 21:22:08 [DEBUG] Initializing BCCSP with software options &{SecLevel:256 HashFamily:SHA2 FileKeystore:0xc00035ee10 DummyKeystore:<nil> InmemKeystore:<nil>}
2021/07/11 21:22:08 [DEBUG] Closing server DBs
Error: Failed to get BCCSP with opts: Could not initialize BCCSP PKCS11: Invalid config. It must not be nil.
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend modifying the config file of fabric-ca-server (fabric-ca-server-config.yaml) instead of trying to override entries in it via environment variables which is what you are trying to do. I believe the problem is you can't override entries that aren't actually defined in the config file.

Comment: I tried that too but I’m getting this error ```fatal error: unexpected signal during runtime execution
[signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0x16870 pc=0x16870]```

Comment: Well that's a completely different problem but it's likely the config options were now accepted.

Comment: Yes seems like they are accepted. Any idea why am I getting that error? I have seen the same errors for peers in other StackOverflow question it was suggested to add ```GODEBUG=netdns=go``` in env variables but that doesn't work with CA containers

Comment: Sorry completely impossible to say from that error message except that some code somewhere tried to jump to an invalid memory location. Maybe raise another stack overflow with complete details such as full stack trace, operating system etc

Comment: That happens when I change the BCCSP to PKCS11 and restart the CA container

Comment: I gathered that it occurred when using the PKCS11 option, but it doesn't help in explaining the error.

Comment: Is there any other way I can know how this error is being thrown? There are rarely any examples if you can suggest any reference it would be of great help.

Comment: You should start by looking at the full stack trace rather than just that error to begin with, that stack trace will provide information about what the ca-server was trying to do when it crashed.

Comment: Not sure how exactly it's done but I will try to find out. Thank you @david_k

Comment: if you look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55976809/hyperledger-fabric-ca-fatal-error-unexpected-signal-during-runtime-execution/55978096#55978096 (in this case the netdns issue) you see they post a complete stack trace, I would expect a similar type of stack trace to be output as well (not saying your problem is the netdns issue of course)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234773/discussion-between-saicharan-pogul-and-david-k).